# UICollectionView: ObjC Apple sample code to Swift conversion (could not find member)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, uicollectionview

I tried converting the sample code provided by Apple for the UICollectionView (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/CircleLayout/Introduction/Intro.html) to Swift.

However, when writing (View Controller, Line 82):    `self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: tappedCellPath)), completion: nil)`

I get the error

```
Could not find member 'performBatchUpdates'
```

I therefore don't even get as far as building.

Here is my complete Code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // Custom initialization
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        cellCount = 20
        var tapRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture:")
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // #pragma mark UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 0
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return cellCount!
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewCell? {
        let cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell

        return cell
    }

    func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if (sender.state == .Ended) {
            println("tap")
            var initialPinchPoint : CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)
            var tappedCellPath : NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(initialPinchPoint)

            if (tappedCellPath != nil) {
                cellCount = cellCount!-1
                self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: tappedCellPath)), completion: nil)
            } else {
                cellCount = cellCount!+1
                self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: tappedCellPath)), completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    // pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> Bool {
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> Bool {
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> Bool {
    return false
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, canPerformAction action: String?, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, withSender sender: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return false
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView?, performAction action: String?, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, withSender sender: AnyObject) {

    }
    */

}
```

**Cell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

}
```

**CircleLayout.swift**

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

var cellCount : NSInteger?
var center : CGPoint?
var radius : CGFloat?

var deleteIndexPaths : NSMutableArray?
var insertIndexPaths : NSMutableArray?

class CircleLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var centerX : CGFloat?
    var centerY : CGFloat?


    override func prepareLayout() {
        super.prepareLayout()

        var size : CGSize = self.collectionView.frame.size
        cellCount = self.collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0)
        center = CGPointMake(size.width/2.0, size.height/2.0)
        centerX = center!.x
        centerY = center!.y
        radius = 300
    }

    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return self.collectionView.frame.size
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        var attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
        attributes.size = CGSizeMake(70, 70)
        attributes.center = CGPointMake(0,0)
        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> AnyObject[]! {
        var attributes : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.array()

        for (var i = 0; i<cellCount!; i++) {
            var indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)
            attributes.addObject(self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath))
        }
        return attributes
    }

    override func prepareForCollectionViewUpdates(updateItems: AnyObject[]!) {

        super.prepareForCollectionViewUpdates(updateItems)

        deleteIndexPaths = NSMutableArray.array()
        insertIndexPaths = NSMutableArray.array()

        for update : AnyObject in updateItems{
            if (update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateAction.Delete) {
                deleteIndexPaths!.addObject(update.indexPathBeforeUpdate)
            } else if (update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateAction.Insert) {
                insertIndexPaths!.addObject(update.indexPathAfterUpdate)
            }
        }
    }

    override func finalizeCollectionViewUpdates() {
        deleteIndexPaths = nil
        insertIndexPaths = nil
    }

    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {

        var attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)

        if (insertIndexPaths!.containsObject(itemIndexPath)) {
            if(attributes == false) {
                attributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)
                attributes.alpha = 0.0
                attributes.center = CGPointMake(center!.x, center!.y)
            }
        }
        return attributes
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        var attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)

        if (deleteIndexPaths!.containsObject(itemIndexPath)) {
            if(attributes == false) {
                attributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)
                attributes.alpha = 0.0
                attributes.center = CGPointMake(center!.x, center!.y)
                attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1,1.0)
            }
        }
        return attributes

    }

}
```

Comment: Please remove all the irrelevant code. Seriously - no-one's going to read all that.

Comment: 1. Have you tried splitting the line that fails into a few lines (with temporary variables)? Because of Swift compiler bugs, sometimes it magically helps.
2. Have you tried cleaning the target and rebuilding? That also helps sometimes.

Comment: I don't know in which part of the code the problem is rooted. If I just post the code that I think is relevant I might miss the part that's causing the problem.

Comment: @radex - I tried doing that but this didn't get me very far. Could you give me an example what I should try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

performBatchUpdates expects a block as its first argument. I believe this will work as intended:

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
   self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: tappedCellPath))
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This solved that problem! Thank you so much – I must have been blind!